# Reassembling TCP Segments

Tags: tcp, packet, wireshark

While observing network traffic in wireshark, i see that wireshark reassembles packets like:

```
[Reassembled TCP Segments (4233 bytes): #1279(2133), #1278(2100)]

Packet #1278: blahblah, Seq: 1538, Ack:3074, Len: 2133
Packet #1279: blahblah, Seq: 2998, Ack:3074, Len: 2100
```

(lengths are fictional values)

Im looking to reassemble tcp packets that i receive through sharppcap

Does wireshark use Ack to know what segments belong to each other?

What is the Seq value refer to?

If not, how does it reassemble them?

Comment: http://wiki.wireshark.org/TCP_Reassembly and see http://wiki.wireshark.org/TcpPduTime

Comment: This doest really explain how to know what packets belong to each other to reassemble them, these pages just say that you can reassemble tcp packets with wireshark and the tcp.pdu.time is kept track of internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SEQ values are counted in bytes, so if you receive a 100 byte segment with `SEQ == 5`, you know the next segment in the sequence will have a `SEQ == 105`.

The ACK indicates the next SEQ value that the sender expects to see from its peer. So the only reason you're seeing the same ACK value in multiple packets is because only one side is transmitting. By keeping the ACK the same, With each transmission, the host is basically saying it hasn't received anything new.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence number identifies the first byte in the segment. As part of connection establishment each peer picks a random sequence number for the first byte that it will send. Thereafter, the next sequence number is the previous sequence number plus the number of bytes in the previous segment.

I don't understand your question about whether Wireshark uses Ack to reassemble segments.

Comment: From what it looks like in wireshark, all the packets with the same ack are reassembled down the line...i think

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong,
It is not up to TCP to reassemble the PDU..TCP's job is to make sure the tcp segments arrive in order(seq, ack), it does not care about the upper layer protocols..

e.g. a long HTTP response(suppose you are downloading some large file), TCP does not know (neither does it care) where the end of the request is, because that's HTTP's job

Comment: you've got it backwards realdreams. the network stack guarantees to the application that tcp segments will arrive in correct order. tcp applications will never deal with mis-ordered packet data. this is how some Denial of Service attacks work. they generate a large stream of data with a chunk missing from at or near the beginning. this forces the receiving network stack to buffer it until it runs out of room.

udp applications must however. there is no guarantee by the network stack that udp payloads arrive in order, or that they arrive at all.